# PS: How to See the Border of the Canvas

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I loaded some template, and ever since when I make a new image no matter how much I zoom out all I see is white, there is no way to tell where the canvas ends, even though it does end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your *Canvas Color* (the background color of Photoshop) has somehow been set to *Custom* and that the custom color is white.

If you right-click outside the document you can choose the background color you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to View > Show > ... ?

Have you tried changing to dark mode and having the background white when you start a new document?

Have you tried selecting the artboard checkbox in the dialog box when you start a new document?

[image: screen shot of photoshop view dropdown menu]